# Form validation does nothing to the form, NO HTML, ONLY JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to learn JS so i am writing code only in JS (there is only up to the body tag in my html code that uses the script).

I am trying in the condition mentioned above, to write a login form and validate it with a validation function.
For some reason nothing happens when I submit the form (I believe its not even calling the validate function, since I put an alert in the beginning of it).

My code:

```
function validateLogin() {
    alert("CHECK");
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    if (username === "admin" && pass === "admin") {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Wrong username or password!");
        return false;
    }
}

var loginDiv = document.createElement('div');
loginDiv.className = 'loginDiv';
var loginForm = document.createElement('form');
loginForm.className = 'loginForm';
loginForm.onsubmit = "return validateLogin()";
var username = document.createElement('input');
username.id = 'username';
var pass = document.createElement('input');
pass.id = 'pass';
pass.type = 'password';
var subm = document.createElement('input');
subm.type = 'submit';
loginForm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Username:"));
loginForm.appendChild(username);
loginForm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
loginForm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Password:"));
loginForm.appendChild(pass);
loginForm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
loginForm.appendChild(subm);
loginForm.action = "#";
loginForm.method = "post";

loginDiv.appendChild(loginForm);
document.body.appendChild(loginDiv);
```

**edit**    I found that changing 
    loginForm.onsubmit = "return validateLogin()"; 
into

```
loginForm.onsubmit = validateLogin;
```

solved it for me, for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you're targeting the DOM object, not the value.
Instead of:

```
var username = document.getElementById('username');
```

use:

```
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
```

Of course this is not a good way to build an authentication system, but since it's for learning purposes, we'll go on with it. I would also not recommend using all these "appendChild" functions to create HTML.
There are better ways of doing it. Look into things like MuschacheJS and how they do rendering.

Edit:

You also need to call the function validateLogin();
You could do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  validateLogin();
});
```

This code assumes that there is a button with id **submitButton**, but you already know how to create that.

Comment: thanks, but regardless to the good point you showed me, I don't even see the alert in the beginning of the function.. is that due to a syntax error or does it not even go into the function?

Comment: I've updated the code to answer your question. Also check out JSlint.com where you can check your code online. When you're more comfortable with it, use it in your own editor so you don't have to copy/paste code.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change your button code to the following:

```
 var subm = document.createElement('button');
 subm.innerHTML = 'click me';
 subm.onclick = validateLogin();
 subm.type = 'submit';
```

Comment: Thanks, should not it be  subm.onclick = return validateLogin();?

Comment: At this point using the code you supplied, it automatically launches the alert in the beginning of the validateLogin() function, and does not let me even see the form

Answer (score 0):

Your `onsubmit` attribute is not added to your form. To fix this, use `.setAttribute` as you can see in the code below.

A second problem is, that you don't get the value of your input fields, but the full node. For that, you need to append `.value`.

If you don't want that the page reloads (or redirects to any page given in the `action` attribute of your form when true login credentials, prepend `event.preventDefault()` to your `validateLogin()`.

```
function validateLogin() {    
    alert("CHECK");
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    if(username === "admin" && pass ==="admin"){
        return true;
    } else{
        alert("Wrong username or password!");
        return false;
    }
}
var loginDiv = document.createElement('div');
loginDiv.className = 'loginDiv';
    var loginForm = document.createElement('form');
        loginForm.className = 'loginForm';
        // .setAttribute() allows to set all kind of attributes to a node
        loginForm.setAttribute("onsubmit", "return validateLogin()");
        var username = document.createElement('input');
                username.id = 'username';
            var pass = document.createElement('input');
                pass.id = 'pass';
                pass.type = 'password';
            var subm = document.createElement('input');
            subm.type = 'submit';
        loginForm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Username:"));
        loginForm.appendChild(username);
        loginForm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        loginForm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Password:"));
        loginForm.appendChild(pass);
        loginForm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        loginForm.appendChild(subm);
        loginForm.action = "#";
        loginForm.method = "post";

    loginDiv.appendChild(loginForm);
document.body.appendChild(loginDiv);
```

Comment: Great answer thanks. At this point, nothing happens when I submit the form, not even the alert("CHECK"); statement

Comment: @Sharonica I have tested the code I posted in a blank file which only includes a `<html>` and `<body>` tag and wrapped `<script>` around the above JavaScript code and it works fine for me.

Comment: Alright, I will keep digging, maybe something else is preventing my code to work well. Thank you very much

Comment: @Sharonica Which browser do you use to test this?

Comment: I tried both Chrome and IE, it works after I edited the code (I edited the question)